# How to block a someone from commenting?

Tags: spam

I keep getting spammed by the same user, well different name and site listed but always the same email, IP, and comment.

the email is `1p@ultradrugbuy.com`, the IP is `31.184.238.9`, and the message is long and always the same.

I want to do 2 things:

- How can I block this person from commenting?
- I have over a hundred pending from them, is there a way to mark them all as
  spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings > Discussion > Comment Blacklist`. You can blacklist comments based on content, name, url, e-mail, or IP.

To mark the comments as spam, what I would do, is to do a search for his IP and then there is a checkbox that will select all, then just mark as spam. Trick is, it only applies to the comments listed on the page, but it is still better to do a few and a lot.

Comment: Was going to suggest the same so gave you a +1. However do note, blocking my IP isn't a guaranteed solution by any means as IPs can easily be changed or spoofed by a savy hacker. IP banning can in some cases result in blocking legitimate users(something anyone doing IP bans should be aware of). Yes it's still viable as an immediate solution, i'm simply saying don't rely on it to save you from all spammers without there being the potential of having a negative impact on legitimate visitors.