# Programmatically block commenting by restricting view of comment form

Tags: comments, comment-form

A forum bridge plugin has the following:

```
        // Check role is_banned (int 1||0 )
    if ( $this->visitor['is_banned'] === 1 ) {
        // remove capability from the user and any roles
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $user->set_role( 'subscriber');
        $user->remove_all_caps();
        $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

        if ( is_multisite() ) {
            update_user_status( $user_id, 'spam', 1 );
        }
    }
```

The database shows no wp_capabilities. Unfortunately, the WordPress user can still submit comments.

Is it possible to create a role without commenting abilities?

This question only is for settings

[How to block a someone from commenting?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/how-to-block-a-someone-from-commenting)

I'm curious if a filter could be added to remove the comment form from anyone with a particular role. In other words, create a role called 'banned' and if that role is present then call a function which removes the comment form from view OR create a user meta called banned, set to 1, test for presence of flag to show form.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you mean this kind of approach:

```
add_filter( 'init', function()
{
    $u = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $u->exists() && in_array( 'banned', $u->roles, true ) )
        add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
} );
```

where we check if the current user has the custom *banned* role.

If that's the case then we force all comments to be *closed* through the `comments_open` filter.

That means this user should not be able to see the *comment form* or post a comment directly to `wp-comments-post.php`, because of the `comments_open()` checks.

Comment: Here's my more [detailed answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/232178/26350) on a related topic.

Comment: I didn't follow this exactly but it has the important line. Chose to use a meta value for banned == 0 or 1. If 1 then `add_filter('comments_open',__return_false')` else `add_filter('comments_open',__return_true')` -- seems to work well. Thank you.