# Only subscriber role user can comment not other

Tags: comments

I have marked the option - " Users must be registered and logged in to comment  " in Admin panel Setting -> Discussion section but i want only subscriber role user can comment not other roles type user.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231903/programmatically-block-commenting-by-restricting-view-of-comment-form/231921#231921) kind of approach can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding a snippet to the theme file where the comments form is loaded that checks to make sure there is a logged in user and then, if that user a Subscriber, then show the comments form to them.  The examples below use the Twenty Sixteen theme:

In comments.php:

```
// First, get the current user and check their role
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    // The current user has the subscriber role, show the form
    comment_form( array(
        'title_reply_before' => '<h2 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
        'title_reply_after'  => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

This way, only those users with the subscriber role will see the comments form.

Comment: Sorry, but this show/hide the comment form for the frontend. That doesn't mean that only subscribers **can** comment. Maybe this one combined with @pallavi's answer could do the job.

Comment: @cybmeta While is true that my code does not disable commenting for the other roles, one cannot comment without access to the form.  Without the form, commenting is not possible, and since this is doable via a theme php file rather than the functions file, it is less invasive.  You could combine the two answers, yes, but that's just more code that might not be necessary.  It depends, really, on how the OP wishes to proceed.

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong. Anyone can send data from the frontend with or without a form, even more, anyone can inject a form into your page. Remember that frontend can be totally manipulated without your control. You need to block it server-side; **when comment data is received you need to check the role of the commenter**, that is the only true way.

Comment: @cybmeta I would hope that there would be security in place to prevent things like basic injection and unauthorized requests would be dropped.  And you don't want to JUST check the role on comment receipt because that's code being fired that doesn't need to be.  Yes, it's good as a just-in-case, but if every comment is being moderated for role on submit, that's a bunch of work your back-end doesn't need to do.  Again, it's up to the OP and his preference on approaches.  He didn't ask for the most secure method, he just asked how.

Comment: I think you don't fully understand what I mean. It is not a security issue, it is just how internet and web applications works and you need to be aware about it. You need to check requests server-side. Again, your code hide a form but it doesn't mean that only "subscribers" are allowed to comment. Sorry but from my point of view it is not a good solution. If you want we can continue the discussion in chat room and I will explain it deeply.

Comment: @cybmeta  Trust me, I'm already aware.  I run quite a few WordPress sites, and I'm not saying you're wrong - I'm saying that checking the data on the back-end is correct, but my answer is also still correct.  He didn't ask for the most secure method - I have my answer on the assumption that he was implementing proper security measure elsewhere as well.  What I gave him was the most light-weight answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first time the core calls `wp_get_current_user()` is within the `WP::init()` method.

To better understand the context, we see that it's right after the `after_setup_theme` hook and just before the `init` hook <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c73c23c423a54fd8592368e234733990e2a64169/wp-settings.php#L392-413)</sup>:

```
do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );

// Set up current user.
$GLOBALS['wp']->init();

do_action( 'init' );
```

where `WP::init()` is defined as <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c73c23c423a54fd8592368e234733990e2a64169/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L588-596)</sup>:

```
public function init() {
    wp_get_current_user();
}
```

The `wp_get_current_user()` is a wrapper for `_wp_get_current_user()` that contains calls to `wp_set_current_user()` in various ways, e.g. with `wp_set_current_user(0)` for logged-out users.

Here's one suggestion, hook into the `set_current_user` action within the `wp_set_current_user()`:

```
/**
 * Comments only open for users with the 'subscriber' role
 */
add_action( 'set_current_user', function() use ( &$current_user )
{
   if(     $current_user instanceof \WP_User 
        && $current_user->exists() 
        && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $current_user->roles, true ) 
    )
        return;

    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );

} );
```

If the current user has the *subscriber* role then do nothing. For all other users or visitors the comments are forced closed.

I might be too cautious checking for the `\WP_User` object instance, but I keep it anyway, as it's possible to mess with the `$current_user`, as with many other things in WordPress ;-)

The reason for using `$current_user` here, instead of calling `wp_get_current_user()`, is to avoid a possible infinite loop, but there are ways to handle that if needed. It's also tempting to play with the `determine_current_user` filter.

For  *visitors* (not logged in) the `wp_get_current_user()` will return a `\WP_User` object with ID as `0` and roles as an empty array. That's because of the `wp_set_current_user(0)` calls mentioned earlier.

Here `$current_user->exists()` is a wrapper for `! empty( $current_user->ID)`.

I agree with @TammyShipps regarding the array casting of the roles, but as noted by @cybmeta, only hiding the comment form will not stop other users from being able to comment.

Another approach is a little rewrite of my recent answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231921/26350):

```
/**
 * Comments only open for users with the 'subscriber' role
 */
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $u = wp_get_current_user();

    if( $u->exists() && in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $u->roles, true ) )
        return;

    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
} );
```

Both of these methods should stop direct POST requests to the `wp-comments-post.php` file, because of the `comments_open()` check there. I haven't checked but I think it will also work with xml-rpc.

We might also try the `pre_comment_on_post` hook to stop the comment handling by e.g. throwing an `\WP_Error`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code check if user is not subscriber then comment form will not display. Comment form only show when user is login and and user role is subscriber.

```
  add_filter( 'init', 'manage_comment');

    function manage_comment()
    {
     global $current_user;

     $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
     $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    if ($user_role!='subscriber')
    { 
     add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Why??? Simply dumping code is bad, all code should be accompanied by some kind of explanation what the code does and how it works. For newbies, this is pretty useless